# CPU usage in C (as percentage)

Tags: c, ubuntu, lua

How can I get CPU usage as percentage using C?

I have a function like this:

```
static int cpu_usage (lua_State *L) {
    clock_t clock_now      = clock();
    double  cpu_percentage = ((double) (clock_now - program_start)) / get_cpus() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    lua_pushnumber(L,cpu_percentage);
    return 1;
}
```

"program_start" is a clock_t that I use when the program starts.

Another try:

```
static int cpu_usage(lua_State *L) {
    struct rusage ru;
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &ru);

    lua_pushnumber(L,ru.ru_utime.tv_sec);
    return 1;
}
```

Is there any way to measure CPU? If I call this function from time to time it keeps returning me the increasing time... but that´s not what I want.

PS: I'm using Ubuntu.

Thank you! =)

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu @FiddlingBits =)

Comment: Use `getrusage()` to get the CPU time used by the current process.

Comment: @Barmar I tried (I edited my post)... but it keeps returning an incremental number... =/ ...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to divide the delta CPU time by the delta clock time to get a percentage.

Comment: You mean this @Barmar? clock_t clock_now  = clock();
return ru.ru_utime.tv_sec / ru.ru_utime.tv_sec; (following the second function)

Comment: You need to save the CPU and calendar time at the beginning of the period in static variables. Then when you want the percentage, you get the current CPU and calendar times, and calculate `(cpu_now-cpu_start)/(calendar_now-calendar_start)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function should work as expected. From [`clock`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/clock.html)

> The clock() function shall return the implementation's best approximation to the *processor time used by the process* since the beginning of an implementation-defined era related only to the process invocation.

This means, it returns the CPU time for this process.

---

If you want to calculate the CPU time relative to the wall clock time, you must do the same with [`gettimeofday`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gettimeofday.html). Save the time at program start

```
struct timeval wall_start;
gettimeofday(&wall_start, NULL);
```

and when you want to calculate the percentage

```
struct timeval wall_now;
gettimeofday(&wall_now, NULL);
```

Now you can calculate the difference of wall clock time and you get

```
double start = wall_start.tv_sec + wall_start.tv_usec / 1000000;
double stop = wall_now.tv_sec + wall_now.tv_usec / 1000000;
double wall_time = stop - start;
double cpu_time = ...;
double percentage = cpu_time / wall_time;
```

Comment: But it doesn't divide CPU time by clock time to get a percentage.

Comment: A percentage in relation to what?

Comment: CPU time as a percentage of real time is what it usually means. Like `top` reports.

Comment: Thanks @OlafDietsche =) ...can I measure cpu_time just using clock_t?  "double cpu_time = ((double) (cpu_now - cpu_start)) / 1000000;"

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Although this value is in clock ticks only, you must divide by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` to get CPU seconds. As you already have seen there are several ways, you can use `clock`, `getrusage` or `times`.

Comment: Seems that is working.. 0.96,0.97,0.974,0.9733... =D